# How to resolve Javascript uncaught referenceerror onchange of DropDownList?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to set Label text property based on the selection of dropdownlist data. I have a label control which stores current date and I am selecting number of days from dropdownlist to be added with current date and display the new date within another label control. While doing this I am getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: findDate is not defined.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function findDate() {
    var selectvalid = $("select[id$=ddlvalid]").val();
            if (selectvalid == "Select Validity") {
                alert("Please Select Validity");
            }
            else if (selectvalid == "Upto 7 Days") {

                var today = new Date();
                var tomorrow = new Date(today);
                tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 7);

                var dd = tomorrow.getDate();
                var mm = tomorrow.getMonth() + 1;
                var y = tomorrow.getFullYear();

                var output = tomorrow.getFullYear() + '/' + (mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + mm + '/' + (dd < 10 ? '0' : '') + dd;
                $("span[id$=lblenddt]").text(output);
            }
            else if (selectvalid == "Upto 15 Days") {
                var today = new Date();
                var tomorrow = new Date(today);
                tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 15);


                var dd = tomorrow.getDate();
                var mm = tomorrow.getMonth() + 1;
                var y = tomorrow.getFullYear();

                var output = tomorrow.getFullYear() + '/' + (mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + mm + '/' + (dd < 10 ? '0' : '') + dd;
                document.getElementById("<%=lblenddt.ClientID%>").innerHTML = output;
            }
            else if (selectvalid == "Upto 30 Days") {
                var today = new Date();
                var tomorrow = new Date(today);
                tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 30);

                var dd = tomorrow.getDate();
                var mm = tomorrow.getMonth() + 1;
                var y = tomorrow.getFullYear();

                var output = tomorrow.getFullYear() + '/' + (mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + mm + '/' + (dd < 10 ? '0' : '') + dd;
                document.getElementById("<%=lblenddt.ClientID%>").innerHTML = output;
            }
    };
        window.onload = function() {
            var d = new Date();
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = d.getDate();
            var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
            document.getElementById("<%=lblenqmdon.ClientID%>").innerHTML = output;
        };
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td>Enquiry Made On:</td>
    <td>
        <label id="lblenqmdon" runat="server"></label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Enquiry Validity:</td>
    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlvalid" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" onchange="javascript:findDate();">
                                <asp:ListItem>Select Validity</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Upto 7 Days</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Upto 15 Days</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Upto 30 Days</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Enquiry Valid Upto:</td>
    <td>
        <label id="lblenddt" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static"></label>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define a function findDate in javascript you have written `$(function findDate()`  change it to `function findDate()` also you don't need to bind `onchange` again in javascript code you have already binded this in dropdown html `onchange="javascript:findDate();"`

```
function findDate() {

            var selectvalid = $("#ddlvalid option:selected").text();
            if (selectvalid == "Select Validity") {
                alert("Please Select Validity");
            }
            else if (selectvalid == "Upto 7 Days") {

                var today = new Date();
                var tomorrow = new Date(today);
                tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 7);

                var dd = tomorrow.getDate();
                var mm = tomorrow.getMonth() + 1;
                var y = tomorrow.getFullYear();

                var output = tomorrow.getFullYear() + '/' + (mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + mm + '/' + (dd < 10 ? '0' : '') + dd;
                document.getElementById("<%=lblenddt.ClientID%>").value = output;
            }
            else if (selectvalid == "Upto 15 Days") {
                var today = new Date();
                var tomorrow = new Date(today);
                tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 15);


                var dd = tomorrow.getDate();
                var mm = tomorrow.getMonth() + 1;
                var y = tomorrow.getFullYear();

                var output = tomorrow.getFullYear() + '/' + (mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + mm + '/' + (dd < 10 ? '0' : '') + dd;
                document.getElementById("<%=lblenddt.ClientID%>").innerHTML = output;
            }
            else if (selectvalid == "Upto 30 Days") {
                var today = new Date();
                var tomorrow = new Date(today);
                tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 30);

                var dd = tomorrow.getDate();
                var mm = tomorrow.getMonth() + 1;
                var y = tomorrow.getFullYear();

                var output = tomorrow.getFullYear() + '/' + (mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + mm + '/' + (dd < 10 ? '0' : '') + dd;
                document.getElementById("<%=lblenddt.ClientID%>").innerHTML = output;
            }
      }
        window.onload = function() {
            var d = new Date();
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = d.getDate();
            var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
            document.getElementById("<%=lblenqmdon.ClientID%>").innerHTML = output;
        };
    });
```

**Edit**

You have so set `ClientIDMode="static"` on dropdown and label to be found by javascript by exact id

Comment: I followed what you suggested. .But there is no change in my label **lblenddt**
I have edited my code please check and guide me.

Comment: Remove `$("#ddlvalid").change(function () {` and its closing brackets accordingly.

Comment: Also use clientId in javascript like you have done for label `"<%=ddlvalid.ClientID%>"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79552/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-omi).

Comment: Just to make sure  if you are hitting the function put an alert in start on function to see if it appears.

Comment: Yes. .still not able to assign value to selectvalid. Dropdownlist selected value is not working.

Comment: have you set ClientIDMode=static on dropdown ?

Comment: I have debugged the code and I am getting the desired value in my **output** variable. But the value is not displayed within label lblenddt.